# Does Tensorflow reuse computation for every sess.run() node?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the documentation of Tensorflow's `Session.run()` function ([link here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/client.html#Session.run)) it is said that the `fetches` argument can be a list of nodes, to get the output of multiple graph nodes at the same time, instead of just one.

My question is, if such nodes are related and have dependencies between them, will the computation be shared or each node will have it's own computation?

Let my explain better with an example. Suppose we have the following computation graph:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.placeholder("float")
b = tf.mul(a,3)
c = tf.mul(b,-2)

sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run([b, c], feed_dict={a:2}))
```

The output will be

```
[6.0, -12.0]
```

But will the computation to get `b` be reused to get `c`? Or will `b` and `c` be computed independently even though they share some operations?

My guess is that the computation will be reused, but I can't find the answer in the documentation.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, computations are reused. It's a very straightforward optimization, so it would be silly if it weren't implemented

Comment: Ok, thanks, I thought that the computations would be shared but I didn't know for sure. Thanks for your confirmation!